# WPF - example with DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid with 2 columns. One column contains role information, the other column should have a combo box with a list of available users. The data in the combobox is unrelated to the data in the first column.

I'm thrown off by the fact that the combobox does not have a datacontext, only an itemsource and I can't seem to use binding either.

What is the method that uses two different data sets for the data in a table and in the combo box?

Comment: @UnkownCoder, questions with phrases like "can some point me to" could be identified as off-topic (see [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the columns in the datagrid dont have a datacontext, as they are never added to the visual tree. sound a bit wierd but have a look at [vinces blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx), its got a good example of the visual layout. once the grid is drawn the cells have a data context and you can set the combo boxes items source in them using normal bindings (not static resources..)

you can access the combo box items source as such

```
   <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
      <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=MyBindingPath}" />
        </Style>
      </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
   </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633800/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboxbox-itemssource-binding-to-a-collection-of-collection) and also [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=46627) for some code

Comment: You have to do the same for the `ElementStyle` property, see here: https://tech-disasters.blogspot.com/2016/10/mvvm-datagridcomboboxcolumn-binding.html

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `DataGridTextColumn` one uses a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` instead. Then one fills in the data using the `ItemsSource`, which in the below example points to an external `enum` in the static resource, and finally one binds the result to the target object which will hold the user selection in the `SelectedItemBinding`.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="MySelections"  
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MySelectionsProperty}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySelectionsEnum}}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

See a full example on MSDN at [DataGridComboBoxColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx)