# DataGrid that uses binding to create table with comboboxes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a `DataGrid` that should have a text column for the first column, and then the succeeding columns should be combo boxes with a different set of items for each column.

The problem is that the number of combo box columns is dynamic, as are the items that should be in each column's combo box.  They are known at binding time, but not at compilation.

Can I bind to a `DataGrid` in this fashion?  I have figured out how to bind to the table to get the values into `TextBox` columns, but I don't know how to get the combo box columns.

Comment: The conditions sound a bit too lose.  Have you thought about creating a custom control.  What type of data will be bound to the comboboxes and how do you know how many column are needed?  Then what does the user need to be able to do with the rows (sort, add, delete etc).  What is the type of collection the datagrid uses.  More info please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a DataGrid, you could use a ListView with a GridView, and create the GridView through a converter which binds to some object containing the necessary information on what the columns should be. This is what I usually do if I want to bind to an array of unknown dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This was originally posted as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724180/problem-binding-datagridcomboboxcolumn-itemssource)

The columns in the datagrid don't have a datacontext, as they are never added to the visual tree. Sounds a bit wierd but have a look at [vince's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx), its got a good example of the visual layout. Once the grid is drawn the cells have a data context and you can set the combo boxes items source in them using normal bindings (not static resources..)

You can access the combo box items source as such

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn>
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
         <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=MyBindingPath}" />
      </Style>
   </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

This means that you can bind the combo boxes ItemsSource to some property on the row (item).

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633800/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboxbox-itemssource-binding-to-a-collection-of-collection) and also [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=46627) for some code. You will also need to **set the items source for the non edting element** as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903057/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn)