# Bind Data to DataGrid with existing columns in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to bind Data to a DataGridView, where the DataGrid already have columns, and if i have columns like TextBox columns it works perfectly, but the problem is if i have columns like ComboBox.

I am trying to do this in Windows Forms. I am just trying to understand the problem when i load the data to a DataTable from the Database. For example, i am loading the Data from the Database to a Datatable and then i set it as DataSource of the DataGridView, but how i can put the data in customized columns where columns are of ComboBox type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link.

[Binding a Combobox control to a separate source within a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726777/binding-a-combobox-control-to-a-separate-source-within-a-datagrid)

[Binding data with comboBox in DataGridview](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10052218/problem-in-binding-data-with-combobox-in-datagridview.aspx)

[DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx)

[combobox column in datagridview after binding the table](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d142e5db-8e16-4b4b-8bca-d48b362823a1)

Regards