# Unable to get ItemsSource working dynamically for DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagridcolumn

I am trying to bind the `ItemsSource` property of my `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to a property of my ViewModel. I understand that due to some limitations this is not possible without using a static list of some sort or a workaround.

I chose to go the workaround route. I tried every answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724180/problem-binding-datagridcomboboxcolumn-itemssource) StackOverflow thread with no luck, and most recently I tried [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) workaround with no luck either.

Here is my XAML as per my last attempt:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Action"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding DISPLAY_ACTION_ID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="DISPLAY_ACTION_ID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="DISPLAY_ACTION_DESC">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ActionSource}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ActionSource}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I have also tried adjusting the `ItemsSource` binding as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517789/binding-a-wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-with-mvvm) thread with no luck.

Here is my ViewModel property in case it helps:

```
public List<DISPLAY_ACTION> ActionSource
{
    get
    {
        return _actionSource;
    }
}
```

All I am getting is an empty list of values. If I put a breakpoint on the property getter it never breaks, i.e. it seems like the XAML isn't finding the `ActionSource` binding. Any help or guidance on why this might not be working would be greatly appreciated.

Edit - Updated XAML:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          RowHeaderWidth="20"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItemsView}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Action"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding DISPLAY_ACTION_ID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectedValuePath="DISPLAY_ACTION_ID"
                                DisplayMemberPath="DISPLAY_ACTION_DESC">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ActionSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ActionSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Debugging Error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ActionSource; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlockComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`

Comment: @dkozl Yes, that is what doesn't work as per the limitation I mentioned. It is explained in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) thread.

Comment: shouldn't it be an observable collection of <somemodel>

Comment: What is your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` bound to?

Comment: @amnezjak It is bound to `DisplayItemsView`, a `ListCollectionView` of `DISPLAY_ITEM`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your `DataGrid` is bound to a list of `MyItem` objects. You have two options:

a) Each `MyItem` object contains filled `ActionSource` list.

b) Your main ViewModel contains both list of `MyItem` objects (bound to
    `DataGrid`) and the `ActionSource` list. Then you should change the
    ComboBox `ItemsSource` binding to:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ActionSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

In both cases you have to ensure the `SelectedValueBinding` points to a property of `MyItem` object, not `DISPLAY_ACTION` object.

Comment: This still didn't work for me unfortunately. I updated my post to reflect my new XAML showing your changes. Note that the selected value biding of `DISPLAY_ACTION_ID` is in fact a property of the `DisplayItemsView` item so that should be ok.

Comment: So both `DISPLAY_ITEM` and `DISPLAY_ACTION` have `DISPLAY_ACTION_ID` property, right? And they match? If so, this seems OK. Maybe you should post your ViewModel code. Also, try to debug your binding using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1125668/1851106

Comment: Yes they both have `DISPLAY_ACTION_ID`, it is a 1-1 relationship. I will try to debug using your posted method and get back if I have no luck. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip, it did in fact throw an error. I updated my post to include the error message.

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the Window beneath DataGrid. Where is it located on window? Also, try to change `AncestorType` to DataGrid.

Comment: Yup, you were right. It is on a Page, not a Window. Everything works great now. Thanks!