# WPF: Binding DataGrid to a list<Product> having a DataGridComboBoxColumn bound to a list<Category>?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGrid with ItemsSource set to a list of products and
I have a DataGridComboBoxColumn inside the DataGrid with ItemsSource set to a list of categories. That way I want the user to choose a certain category for each product.

I always get the binding error:

BindingExpression path error: 'Categories' property not found on 'object' ''Product' (Hash)

Well I do not want to make the Category list part of the Product entity as 1:N relation, although it would work that way.

I want to keep them separate.

Anyone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Create class with static property like

```
static class ValueLists
{
   public static IEnumerable<Category> Categories {get {... }}
}
```

and use following binding

```
ItemsSource="{x:Static myNs:ValueList.Categories}" />
```

Comment: I found a good link dealing with exactly the same stuff I need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633800/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboxbox-itemssource-binding-to-a-collection-of-collection

Comment: I can not implement INotifyPropertChanged in static class what I need ;-)

instead of static binding wouldnt that work ? =>

ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Categories,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                IsReadOnly="True" Background="White" />

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227001645/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx) is probably relevant to your problem.

> What is happening here?
> The Columns collection is just a property in the Datagrid; this collection is not in the logical (or visual) tree, therefore the DataContext is not being inherited, which leads to there being nothing to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

this is kind of late reply but in order to share the knowledge I found this:

[Binding a WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517789/binding-a-wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-with-mvvm?rq=1)

This answer shows that is not always mandatory to convert the second list to a static class, you can always specify a **RelativeSource** and search for an specific **Ancestor** and then bind to the "other" list you have in your ViewModel.