# Binding a WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I've looked at the answers to [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562934/using-wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-with-mvvm-binding-to-property-in-viewmodel) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903057/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn), but haven't managed to map the content in the answers to the problem I'm attempting to solve. I've reduced it down to the following code (representative of the outcome I'm trying to achieve), and basically want to be able to render the `Person.TitleId` as its corresponding `Title.TitleText` when the row isn't being edited, and have the drop-down bound correctly so that it displays the `TitleText`s in the drop-down and writes the associated `TitleId` back to the `Person` record when its changed.

In short, what do I put in my `<DataGridComboBoxColumn>` to achieve this?

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var viewModel = new ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel();
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
    mainWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Title" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Person}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Titles}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Titles}"/>
                        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="TitleText" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Title.cs

```
public struct Title
{
    public Title(int titleId, string titleText)
        : this()
    {
        TitleId = titleId;
        TitleText = titleText;
    }

    public string TitleText { get; private set; }
    public int TitleId { get; private set; }

    public static List<Title> GetAvailableTitles()
    {
        var titles = new List<Title>();

        titles.Add(new Title(1, "Mr"));
        titles.Add(new Title(2, "Miss"));
        titles.Add(new Title(3, "Mrs"));

        return titles;
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> contacts;
    private List<Title> titles;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        titles = Title.GetAvailableTitles();

        Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Contacts.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smith", TitleId = 2 });
    }

    public List<Title> Titles
    {
        get { return titles; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Contacts
    {
        get { return contacts; }
        set
        {
            if (contacts != value)
            {
                contacts = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Contacts");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could outline what parts of that 'plan' do not work/which actually do. e.g. are you able to locate the list for the ComboBox's ItemsSource?

Comment: Also: From the looks of how you use `Title` the class seems redundant and would be better off being replaced by a `Dictionary<int,string>`.

Comment: @H.B. - As the code stands the grid doesn't show the textual representation of the initial value (i.e. the appropriate TitleText for Person.TitleId), the  drop-down gets populated with {Mr,Mrs,Miss} correctly and selecting an item in the drop-down results in TestMVVM.Models.Title being shown in the grid (TestMVVM.Models being the namespace in the solution, that I stripped out for brevity).

Comment: @H.B. - "Title" is a simplification of my "real" code. I've reduced the *real* code down to this specimen case (in my "real" code, the Title class has more properties and whilst I could distill it down to a `Dictionary<int, string>` for the purposes of the grid, I'd rather not as it's more code) to see if I could solve it myself without any extraneous issues such as database access. Given that the minimal case is the best one to post on stackoverflow, that's what I've done =)

Comment: Oh sorry, i did not realize you compressed it already because it is still kind of huge.

Comment: @H.B. - the grid actually contains 12 columns and obviously the models are rather different. I've got everything else working bar the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`s. They're rapidly turning into the bane of my life! =)

Comment: @Rob, I've managed to add a text representation of title, but I still have an issue with `TitleId` not being populated. Do you consider an option of changing `TitleId` into `Title` reference in `Person` class?

Comment: @Snowbear - One option I considered was making the `ObservableCollection<Person>` be `<ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>` so I could do something like that (`Person` is shared with some other projects so I can't change it), so an answer that does that would work :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a working code. The key point here was to use `SelectedValueBinding` instead of `SelecteItemBinding`.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Title" 
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TitleId}"
                        SelectedValuePath="TitleId"
                        DisplayMemberPath="TitleText"
                        >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Titles}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Titles}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Unbelievable, i was just writing pretty much the exact same thing, well, this round goes to you.

Comment: this works perfectly in my reduced case, I'm going to spend some time integrating it into my actual code to see if it works there (I'm sure it will!). Any chance you could explain *how/why* it works? :)

Comment: `SelectedValuePath` sets the path to the member inside the selected object which represents the selected item of the ComboBox, `DisplayMemberPath` on the other hand sets the path to the member inside the class that should be displayed. The `SelectedValueBinding` will bind the selected value to the property specified in the binding. It's a bit confusing but if you use it a few times it makes sense. E: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797034/confused-with-wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath

Comment: I've integrated it into my "actual" code and it works a treat, thankyou! =)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.  Thank you for the concise working example, @Snowbear.

Comment: THANK YOU, the OP and you save my day!
oh it's friday - beer time :)

Answer (score 2):

@SnowBear's answer worked well for me. But I want to clarify a detail of the binding.

In @Rob's example, both Title and Person classes use TitleID.
Therefore, in @SnowBear's answer, in the binding:

```
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TitleId}"
```

it wasn't immediately obvious to me which class and property was being bound.

Because the SelectedValueBinding attribute appeared on the DataGridComboBoxColumn, it is binding to the ItemsSource of the containing DataGrid. In this case the Contacts collection of Person objects.

In my case, the DataGrid's DataSource collection was attributed with a property that was named different from the ValuePath of the ComboBox's ItemSource collection. So my SelectedValueBinding's value was bound to a different property than the property named in the ComboBox's SelectedValuePath.