# Other ItemsSource in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a `DataGrid dg;` and I would like to display a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with data populated from some list (using binding). Using XAML I have `dg.ItemsSource` properly set but I do not know, how to set the column's `ItemsSource`:

`<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource={?????????} />`

James

Comment: Could you post some code of your Collection ? Why can't you have direct access to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datacontext to get the property you are tying to bind to your DataGridComboBoxColumn.Check the below post

[Binding a WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517789/binding-a-wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-with-mvvm/5518373#5518373)

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableOptions}" />
```

Here, `AvailableOptions` is a property of a data item bound to the grid row. This property should contain a list of options available in the combo box.

**Update:**

If the collection of options to select from is fixed you could use `ObjectDataProvider` defined in resources. See http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/ccavalli/archive/2006/02/09/34592.aspx for example.

In your case it could be something like this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Options" ObjectType="{x:Type my:MyOptions}"  />
```

-

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Options}}" />
```

Comment: No, that's not so simple because I'd like to populate this column (each row) with some fixed Collection and I do not have direct access to it. I need somehow change context but I do not know how.