# How to change DataGridComboBoxColumn's DataContext (WPF/C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I am using MVVM with WPF, `Window.DataContext` is set to `myViewModel`. Now, I have `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in the DataGrid and I would like to set the `ItemsSource` for this column to some property of `myViewModel`.

How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Other ItemsSource in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122279/other-itemssource-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn >
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
              <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.YourProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
         </Style>
      </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. YourCollectionProperty is the property of CURRENT ROW, not the property of the main model.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the problem correctly in first sight