# DataGridComboBoxColumn binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have seen a few posts on here with people getting confused on how to bind to a DataGridComboBoxColumn,

I have

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Collection}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="Name" Width="70">
```

which didnt work..

So I used

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemBinding="{Binding Collection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"> Header="Name" Width="70">
```

Which again didn't work, why is binding to a datagridcombo different to a original combo box.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

which does work

What is the correct method of binding to a combo box inside a DataGrid?

---Edit---

I might have found the problem, I have a DataGrid binding to a ItemSource, however, I want the ComboBoxColumn to be bounded to a different Itemsource, is this possible?

Cheers

Comment: Might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5518373/632337.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to **`ItemsSource`** property. Set it in **`EditingElementStyle`**.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Collection}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

---

In case you want `ItemsSource` to bind to collection which is outside of DataGrid underlying source object, you can do that as well.

Say you have collection `AnotherCollection` residing in ViewModel of Window/UserControl, you can bind with it using `RelativeSource` markup extension.

Also, you have to set `SelectedItemBinding` to the property where you want to set the value selected from ComboBox and declare same style under ElementStyle of DataGridComboBoxColumn.
Suppose property name is `Name` to which you want to bind.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.AnotherCollection,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                         AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.AnotherCollection,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                         AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work, however, when I pick a value from the combobox, it disappears when I click off of it, is this the normal behaviour with the code above?

Comment: You need to add `SelectedItemBinding` to the property name to which you want to set the value to and also need to add the same style under ElementStyle. Let me update answer with it.

Comment: Thanks, the combo box now has the selected item, but it crashes the grid! (! appears on the row) I guess this is the itemsource complaining and not the XAML code that is wrong?

Comment: When I select a item from the combo box, I then try to click off of it and a ! appears on the side of the row and the row crashes (I cant add/edit etc)

Comment: It seems you some kind of validation in place in your code. Not an issue with the above XAML.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right, will mark as correct, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Robit and anyone else who may be interested,

I found why the ! kept coming up in the row, it was due not putting

  <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>

in both EditElementStyle and EditingStyle attributes. I am not sure updating the code above is necessary, is up to you.

Might help someone!

Comment: Sure I have updated it in case someone needs it in future. Thanks..!! :)