# ADO.NET DataGrid String Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections, datagrid

I have a Datagrid, on start up I set its set of columns then I bind it to a List> in order to fill it with data. Each nested list has the same number of items as the number of columns I got, but... I don't get nothing shown... What's the correct practice to bind a 2D collection to a DataGrid ?

Code Sample

```
List<List<String>> rows = SomeFunctionThatReturnsTheRows();
this.grid.ItemsSource = rows;
```

Thank you,
Miloud B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then how about this

```
var rows = new List<List<string>>()
      {
          new List<string>() {"List1-1", "List1-2", "List1-3"},
          new List<string>() {"List2-1", "List2-2", "List2-3"}
      };
GridView gv = new GridView();
this.grid.View = gv;
gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn(){DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(".[0]")});
gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn(){DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(".[1]")});
gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn(){DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(".[2]")});
this.grid.ItemsSource = rows;
```

Comment: You knocked it down thank you dean ! I adapted this to DataGridView and it works ! But only one concern: grid.ItemsSource = rows causes the binding of two trailing columns: Capacity and Count which are bound from List... How can I exclude them ?

Comment: you need to turn off AutoGenerateColumns , and create the columns programatically

Comment: Dean you're good ! Thank you very much you taught me a lot today ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to google for is binding to a nested collection, rather than 2D collection - you'll get more results that way :)

Does [WPF DataGrid: DataGridComboxBox ItemsSource Binding to a Collection of Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633800) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you Matt. Although, no it doesn't really answer it :p. The thing is that I can't edit my XAML, I've to find a 100% programmatic solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DataContext = new List<List<string>>()
  {
      new List<string>() {"List1-1", "List1-2", "List1-3"},
      new List<string>() {"List2-1", "List2-2", "List2-3"}
  };

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding .[0]}" /> 
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding .[1]}" /> 
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding .[2]}" /> 
      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

produces this

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dean. only one think, I've to bind programmatically, I can't edit my xaml in my context.