# How do I bind the width property of a WPF Datagrid column?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, width

In a loop which sets up my WPF DataGrid columns, I want to bind the column width to member 'i' in my 'WidthList' with the following code:

```
var bindingColumnWidth = new Binding(string.Format("WidthList[{0}]", i));
customBoundColumn.Width = bindingColumnWidth;
```

However, this gives me the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' to 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You might find this post helpful: [WPF DataGrid: DataGridComboxBox ItemsSource Binding to a Collection of Collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633800/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboxbox-itemssource-binding-to-a-collection-of-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridColumn` has no `SetBinding` method, you should try this:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(customBoundColumn, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, bindingColumnWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I can't check it in my case though since it's still not working. I have started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639050/binding-the-visibility-property-of-a-wpf-datagrid-column-where-is-my-fault) and I will mark this as the answer if/when it all works.