# dataGrid with datagridcomboboxcolumn by autogeneratecolumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to help me solve a problem

I need to populate a datagrid by autommatic way. I have an object with one attribute as Collection I am trying to bind my object in a datagrid and that this attribute seem like a datagridComboBoxColumn. My problem is similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634688/1411394 the difference is that I need to my Datagrid generate by automatic way the columns. When I immplement this binding just my object in the datagrid I just get in my column the word "{Collection}". Is there any way I could do this ? Sorry, I am working with wpf and using pattern mvvm

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the exact technology. I'm guessing WPF but it is hard to be sure from the question.