# Binding a DataGridComboBoxColumn to the DataGrid's ItemsSource in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm creating a `DataGrid` programmatically and have to support `ComboBoxColumns`, too.

After I create `DataGrid`, I set it's `ItemSource` to a collection of a collection of type `BindableList<BindableDictionary>`. `BindableDictionary` is a custom type. Each `BindableDictionary` represents one tuple. It's key is always the name of a column and it's value is a custom class that contains a generic property called `ActualValue`, a `Dictionary<T, string>` called `AllowedValues` and a `boolean` that determines if `AllowedValues` will be used to build a `ComboBoxColumn` or a 'normal' column. Also that class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging`.

That stuff works, aside from the ComboBoxColumn, duh. My problem with the ComboBoxColumn is that I don't know how to get it to use the `AllowedValues` object to fill it's ItemList *and* use the `ActualValue` property to select the correct `Value` from the `AllowedValues` `BindableDictionary` to fill the textarea.

As an example, this is how I bind a textbased column:

```
table.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = column.GUIName, DisplayIndex = column.Position, Binding = new Binding(column.Name + ".ActualValue") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Default, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true, NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true, UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = new UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback(BindingExceptionHandler) } });
```

And yes, that works.

I tried to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to `column.AllowedValues` and set the `DisplayPath` to `"Value"` which does at least display the correct content, but I've no clue how to bind to the `ActualValue` property that is contained in the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`. Also that'd mean that all cells inside a column share the same selectable values, which could lead to problems in the future.

And if I try to bind everything like I did in the `DataGridTextColumn`, nothing is displayed at all. Also there are no items to select.

It'd be awesome if someone has so much as a hint of what I could try.

**edit**

Just saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197004/937093, I tried that but then I get the following message in my output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=AllowedValues; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=33493530); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

My code looks like this:

```
col = new DataGridComboBoxColumn() { Header = column.GUIName, SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(column.Name + ".ActualValue"), SelectedValuePath = "ActualValue" };
table.Columns.Add(col);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(col, DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("AllowedValues"));
```

**edit 2**
okay, found this website: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

I tried to apply the proxy binding stuff (even though I don't get how the Column is *not* part of the visual tree of the DataGrid...where else would it be?!) but it won't work. My code:

```
BindingProxy proxy = new BindingProxy() { Data = table.ItemsSource };
table.Resources.Add("proxy", proxy });
col = new DataGridComboBoxColumn() { Header = column.GUIName, SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Data." + column.Name + ".ActualValue") { Source = proxy }, DisplayMemberPath = "Value", SelectedValuePath = "Key" };
table.Columns.Add(col);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(col, DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Data." + column.Name + ".AllowedValues") });
```

Output in output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyColumn'
>   property not found on 'object' ''BindingList`1' (HashCode=55207835)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Data.MyColumn.ActualValue;
>   DataItem='BindingProxy' (HashCode=45660050); target element is
>   'TextBlockComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValue'
>   (type 'Object')

I understand the problem (it's trying to find the 'MyColumn' object in the BindingList) but I don't understand why that is happening (it should resolve to BindingList[iterator]["MyColumn"], since BindingList contains the BindableDictionary and that's exactly what happens for my 'normal' columns).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. I was using Winforms, so my solution may not work for you. However I'd suggest using something similar to this.

http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

Coupled with this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic

As I had everything working, then found I couldn't sort my datagridview.

I don't have my sourcecode handy, but the general idea was I'd create my comboboxes and textbox columns by hand, then bind my list to it.

After I'd run a function that'd iterate through each row and based on the index ( in my case my comboboxes were the last 3 columns ) I'd add the values for the combobox by hand first, then after those are added, I'd check the value of the combobox and set it to that.

I also included this function in the data error event, for when I added a new column. Also it would randomly crash if I was adding a new row, if I had the autosize set. I had to set these to default, do my editing, then reset it.

Wish I had code to provide, but it might put you on your way. If not when I go in to work tomorrow I'll post some. Comboboxes are a huge pain to work with.